# File Uploader plugin grails

Tags: grails-plugin

How can I add fields to the UFile table created by the file uploader plugin.
Basically I want to set relations between UFile and my table

Answer (score 0):

If you create a domain class in your project in the same package with the same name, it'll be used instead of the one from the plugin.

Comment: I tried doin what u said. But it gave an error..2011-04-28 02:43:53,698 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is

Comment: A cliffhanger of a comment there - the exception that caused the real problem is what's printed after "nested exception is"